# Convert Amount to Words in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on a crystal report, can someone guide me how i can convert currency to words in this format;
(1,502,000.50) One million five hundred and two thousand naira and fifty kobo Only. i have tried:

```
 numberVar x := {@summAmt} - int ({@summAmt});

 if x = 0 then 

 propercase (toWords (int({@summAmt}),0)+ ' Naira Only')

 else 

 propercase (toWords (int({@summAmt}),0)+ ' Naira, and ' + toWords ((x * 100),0) + ' Kobo')
```

Answer (score -1):

To go around this, you will need 2 formulas; create the one i posted earlier, then create then create another formula with the following code:

```
numberVar x := {@summAmt} - int ({@summAmt});
if x > 0 then 
replace ({@convertWords},"Hundred ","Hundred and " )
else
{@convertWords}
```

{@convertWords} is the name of my first formula and @summAmt is the name of the field i am converting.